# Text wrapping in the wp8 app bar

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my Windows Phone 8 app the app bar usually looks like this:

[image]

But for some reason on one of my users with a 1020 it looks like this: (it's a NOKIA RM-877_nam_att_205 3.3.0.2 3051.40000.1346.0001 with OS version 8.0.10517.0)

[image]

(the WP8 emulator also looks like the second one)

Anyone knows why this happens, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `But for some reason on one of my users with a 1020` - Just to add my 5 cents: he has extended screen. Have the same on mine 920, WP8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there some regional dependency and there is no fix yet, since it not accessible from the application. Same problem at the [msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/a752e7d1-f8e7-4b3b-a105-5d19c450a623/how-to-display-applicationbar-menuitem-text-on-multiple-lines?forum=wpdevelop).

Users reported: English-UK, French, German or Dutch - wrap. English-US - truncate.

Answer (score 7):

The default behaviour of English text accompanying an `ApplicationBarIconButton` is for it to be on a single line.

Multi-line support was added for some languages where word length is typically longer than in English. The wrapping was therefore needed for text to not be clipped.

The enabling of multi-line support is dependent upon a combination of device, OEM and regional settings. Developers/apps cannot influence this behaviour.

The expectation of all English text accompanying an icon button is that it should be on a single line. If it ran across multiple lines and then was translated to a language which used longer words for the translation then the translated text would not fit in the available space.

You should only use text that can fit on a single line.
For your examples above, I'd recommend "catalog" and "downloads" as labels for the two buttons on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Icon button text is displayed beneath the icon when the user expands the application bar.
If the length of the string exceeds 7 to 13 characters, depending on the width of the characters
that make up the string, it is clipped.

Menu item text does not wrap and should be limited to 14 to 20 characters in length,
depending on the width of the characters.

Many languages use different amounts of space to convey the same meaning. Therefore,
when choosing menu item or button text, consider the different lengths of the text strings
for the language your app will be in. Assume that an average of 30% more space will be
required for any text. Depending on the language and the phrase, the localized string
might even require twice as much space.